# Different rollover image sizing in different browsers

Tags: html, css

I have created some rollover images here and there on my site, but they fail to be properly substituted by the their corollary on-hover pals.
The strange thing is, different browsers mess up different images, and I have already watched precisely every detail but can not find a principle as to why this particular rollover image is bering hover in they way I do not wish.

I do not know if I am allowed to post a link, but you can just skip it if you deem it an advertisement: pheast.ru. The line of images in { } in the head of the page. It is on the grey background.

Here is the markup:
CSS:

```
a#pic1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(о.png) no-repeat;
  width:200px;
  height:108px;
  background-size: contain;
  border:none;
  margin-right:10px;

}
a#pic1:hover {
  background: url(old-old-doctransicon1.png) no-repeat;
  width:200px;
  height:108px;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

and so on for every next pic.

HTML:

```
<a id="pic1" href="documents.html"></a>
<a id="pic2" href="literature.html"></a>
<a id="pic3" href="media.html"></a>
<a id="pic4" href="webdocuments.html"></a>
<a id="pic6" href="correspondence.html"></a>
```

Comment: HTML:
    <a id="pic1" href="documents.html"></a><a id="pic2" href="literature.html"></a><a id="pic3" href="media.html"></a><a id="pic4" href="webdocuments.html"></a><a id="pic6" href="correspondence.html"></a>

Comment: It looks to be working for me, have you tried a proper refresh on your browser ie (Shift+F5) to see if the images loaded are just cached. (Tested with Chrome and IE [Newest Versions])